# Do I need to publish the chrome extension first before I can test the license?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I query the licensing api I successfully get a JSON object, but it says "result:false;" every time. In other words, that the user has no license at all. Because of this there is no access level - FREE_TRIAL or FULL to show. How do I get the user a license? Do I have to first publish the plugin and then i'm able to get the user a license from the store? The plugin is currently unpublished and saved as a draft. I'm using dev mode for testing and the key in the manifest file to maintain the ID the same. I've already tried using a different test google account but that didn't work. I'm trying to avoid going through the publishing process first if i could because I hear that could take weeks. Which is insane that i would have to wait like 3 weeks just to further do testing. Any help would be appreciated.